# CSS check box problem should select when Ill checked it

Tags: css, checkbox

I created a check box into a div and I created a label.I want that when Ill click to check box(#check_box) that time it (#pop_hidden)will be hidden{display: none}. no problem if I use javascript. I just need a solution

```css
#check_box[type=checkbox]:checked : #pop_hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check_box">
</div>
<div>
  <label id="pop_hidden">CSS is Awesome</label>
</div>
```

Its Working if I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked + #pop_hidden {
    display:none;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="ossm"> 
<label id="pop_hidden">CSS is Awesome</label>



</body>
</html>
```

but I want to use it into the div like the first example

Comment: I'm so sorry for the image, now I include the code.. please check it out

Comment: id means input id (#form-field-field_0adce44-0) and label id (#pop_hidden)

Comment: @MisterJojo can you give me a solution with js snipped

Comment: wou to do a display:none to the div containing the label, or only the label ?

Comment: all of elements who have that only (#pop_hidden)id

Comment: id must be unique, you cannot have more than one. also prefer to use a className

Comment: no problem. I want to use unique for only one element @MisterJojo

Comment: Thank you so much, brother. I hope, God always will help you <3

Comment: you may also considere to validate my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I supppose you are looking for that...

```js
const
  checkBox = document.querySelector('#check_box')
, popHiden = document.querySelector('#pop_hidden') 
  ;
checkBox.oninput = e => 
  {
  popHiden.classList.toggle('noDisplay', checkBox.checked)
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check_box">
</div>
<div>
  <label id="pop_hidden">CSS is Awesome</label>
  <br>
  other content in div
</div>
```